# How to make Vue error show the exact error source line in the code?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt to develop an application.
Currently, when I ran into error, the stack trace looks like this.

[image: Error]

This is very difficult to debug and find the error.
Is there any way to make it show the source file, the function, or the line that is causing the error?